# Ember doesn't update (change) id of related model

Tags: ember.js

Let’s say I have two models: Room and Floor, each room belongs to a floor, and each floor has many rooms. To change the room's floor I need to change the related ‘ID’ inside Room.

But when I’m trying to do it, to update 'floorId', Ember doesn’t send new value to my backend (I can see it in the request payload). Everything else works fine.

```
App.Room = DS.Model.extend
  floor: DS.belongsTo 'floor'
  floorId: DS.attr 'number'

App.Floor = DS.Model.extend
  rooms = DS.hasMany 'room'

App.RoomController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['rooms', 'building', 'floors']

  floorsList: (->
    # Building has many floors, floors has many rooms.
    floors = @get('building').get('floors').get('content')
    arr = []
    arr.addObject(@makeObjList(floor)) for floor in floors
    arr
  ).property('floors.content')

  makeObjList: (e) ->
    # We want to change floor_id, not its number.
    { value: parseInt(e.get('id')), label: parseInt(e.get('number')) }

# edit.emblem
= input floorId label="Floor" as="select" collection="floorsList" value="floorId" optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label"
```

Is this problem related to Ember (e.g. convention, that you can't change the ID this way), or I made a mistake?

Comment: Ember has no idea that `floorId` is supposed to be the ID of the floor. To Ember, `floorId` is just a random field on the `Room` model. You could change it to PI and Ember wouldn't care. If you want to change the floor, you have to change the `floor`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought so, but Ember serialize `floorId` into `floor_id` in the payload (and reset the value to the 'old' one). How can I change the floor then?

Comment: Change the floor by setting the `floor` property to the relevant `Floor` model instance.

Comment: @torazaburo It sends `floor_id: null` in the payload :( I have `room = @get('model')`, `newFloor = @store.find('floor', 2)`, and then `room.set('floor', newFloor)`, `room.save()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember doesn't allow you change IDs of models that have relationships via simple ajax request. I ended up modifying my serializer:

```
App.RoomSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend
  serialize: (record, options) ->
    json = @_super(record, options)
    json.floor_id = record.get('floorId')
    json
```